# can't login in graphical environment

Tags: greeter, pantheon-terminal, user-interface, release-odin, user

I did a fresh new installation of Elementary OS Odin, so I created an account for me (administrator) an another for my daughter (default). I logged many times in my account and also in my daughter's account. Now, I cannot login in graphical environment, but I can login by terminal. I changed my password, but it did not work. I also did chown in .Xauthority, but nothing. Change my password, and nothing. apt-get update, upgrade, and again nothing. It's a brand new installation in a brand new laptop.

Comment: Check ownership and permissions on the .X type files … if incorrect … remove them and try a reboot

Comment: I did it. Nothing works.